# Scaffolding with Symfony2 + FOSRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm newbie with Symfony2 and I need create an REST web service. For each request from client the server should respond with a JSON. I choices FOSRestBundle to do it. Is there some way to Generate entities and their controllers with REST CRUD operations?

Comment: Yes, there is. What kind of sources did you already check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maybe you could have a look at the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html)

```
$ php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

There are also 3rd party bundles to generate other things like CRUD for FOSRestBundle: [voryx/restgeneratorbundle](https://github.com/voryx/restgeneratorbundle)

Comment: voryx/restgeneratorbundle it's great!